# Como fazer o programa sair do loop

Tags: c, loop, while, do-while

No exercício que estou fazendo, é pedido que quando o numero de repetições for 0, acabe a execução, mas quando digito 0 ele não faz nada e continua a ler números.
Ele lê um numero K de repetições, depois as coordenadas centrais de um lugar (pensando num gráfico, essas duas entradas definiriam o 0 do local) e os dois números seguintes são onde fica '?' residencia e com isso é preciso definir onde essa se localiza (noroeste, nordeste, sudeste, sudoeste)

este é o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int K = 1, N, M; //n e m = ponto 0 do grafico, divisas para as regioes
    int X, Y; // onde a residencia se encontra
    int i;

    while(scanf("%d", &K) != 0){

        scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);
        i = K;

        for(; i > 0; i--){
            scanf("%d %d", &X, &Y);

            if(X == N || Y == M){
                printf("divisa\n");
            }

            else if(X > N && Y > M){
                printf("NE\n");
            }
            else if(X < N && Y > M){
                printf("NO\n");
            }
            else if(X > N && Y < M){
                printf("SE\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("SO\n");
            }
        }
    }

    if(K == 0)
        return 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creio que você está interpretando errado o retorno da função scanf. Quando você informa 0 para o valor de K o retorno de `scanf("%d", &K)` será 1.

Comment: Complementando: o `scanf("%d", &K)` retornará 0 se no lugar de você informar algum valor informar apenas EOF (^D) e dessa forma não haverá nenhuma atribuição a K e o retorno da função será 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf()` tem esse protótipo:

```
    int scanf(const char *format, .. variaveis...);
```

Isso quer dizer que ela retorna um `int`. E você deve muito ler. Esse `int` é o total de valores lidos, e pode ser que não tenha lido nada e aí seu programa já era.
`scanf()` não foi escrita para ler dados do teclado e é um pesadelo fazer isso. Tem uma razão para ela ter esse nome: **scan f**ormatted input é o propósito dela. E o teclado é tudo menos entrada formatada: 105 teclas de liberdade. Acho que `scanf()` foi escrita por Ken Thompson, um dos melhores desenvolvedores de todos os tempos. Para ler entrada formatada. A culpa não é dele.

#### Um exemplo como no seu programa

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{  
    for (int X = 1, Y=0; X != 0;)
    {
        printf("Entre dois inteiros [0 0 para sair]: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &X, &Y);
        printf("\tLidos %d e %d\n", X, Y);
    };  // for()
};  // main()
```

Não é um programa bonito :( mas ele lê dois números até o primeiro ser 0. Não testa o retorno de `scanf()`, não tenta consumir dados que tenha sido digitados por engano, nada. Eis um resultado típico

```
Entre dois inteiros [0 0 para sair]: 1 1
        Lidos 1 e 1
Entre dois inteiros [0 0 para sair]: 2 2
        Lidos 2 e 2
Entre dois inteiros [0 0 para sair]: 5 6
        Lidos 5 e 6
Entre dois inteiros [0 0 para sair]: 5



45666
        Lidos 5 e 45666
Entre dois inteiros [0 0 para sair]: 2w
        Lidos 2 e 45666
Entre dois inteiros [0 0 para sair]:    Lidos 2 e 45666
Entre dois inteiros [0 0 para sair]:    Lidos 2 e 45666
Entre dois inteiros [0 0 para sair]:    Lidos 2 e 45666

...
```

#### Em resumo

- quando você digita apenas o óbvio, um número e o outro, ok
- quando você digita um número pode teclar 500 ENTER e a tela anda até aparecer o outro número, mas ai tudo bem
- se você bater a mão em uma letra por exemplo, como o `"2w"` no caso acima, o programa entra em loop e vai "ler" os 2 números de antes, 2 e 45666 no caso, **por toda a eternidade** ou até você cancelar o programa. E a culpa é do programa

#### Porque acontece isso?

alguém digitou de fato `'2'`, `'w'` e depois `ENTER`. `scanf()` faz isso: scan. vai lá e encontra o `w`. E está com a missão de scan dois números. Não tem lá. A função não pode simplesmente descartar o que está lá porque pode ser dado importante. Uma outra função pode ir lá e ler as letras por exemplo. `scanf()` é um *scanner*. Não existe *"lixo"* ou *"limpar o buffer"*: é informação que está lá. Tem que ser consumida pelo programa e não por um scanner esperando ler um `int` e depois outro.

#### Como arrumar essa m3rd@?

- Em geral o melhor é não usar nunca `scanf()` para ler do teclado. Não foi escrita para isso.
- Leia o valor de retorno. Cada especificador, aquele troço que tem um `%` e não dois, equivale a algo pra ser lido. A menos que tenha um asterisco na frente, mas não vou reescrever o manual aqui. Então se está usando `"%d %d"` pode retornar 1, 2 ou zero. Se você não testa a vida segue, na alegria e na tristeza, do jeito que der. Veja o programa de exemplo ao final
- Depois de `scanf()` se satisfazer, leia tudo que tem na linha até e inclusive o `'\n'`, por exemplo usando um loop assim, com `ch` declarado como `int`:

```
    do { ch = getc(stdin); } while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF));
```

- se está usando Windows pode chamar --- de windows.h --- [FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)); o oficial para isso](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/flushconsoleinputbuffer)
- não use `fflush()` para fluxos de entrada. `fflush()` só é garantido para fluxos de saída.
- Pode tentar algo com os especificadores de `scanf()`, `%[1234]` por exemplo aceita apenas esses 4 dígitos. `%[^1234]` aceita tudo exceto esses dígitos. Então `%[^\n]` aceita tudo exceto um `enter`, o tal `newline`, e se estiver lendo como texto vai ler a linha toda
- pode ler letras com `fgetc()` ou linhas com `fgetc()`, mais seguro. E depois converter para os dígitos usando as dúzias de funções em C, como `strtol()`
- **mesmo assim pode dar errado**. Quando você não pode arriscar zoar a tela ou ler algo impróprio você

  - define a lista de teclas aceitas
  - lê sem eco e sem mudar o cursor
  - se for válido você mostra a letra e avança o cursor, senão por exemplo toca um beep curto ou vibra
  - se leu o campo volta tudo ao normal e processa o valor. É o que se faz no banco, na loja... Isso quando o equipamento obriga a ler caracteres e não tem interface gráfica

#### De volta ao seu programa

```
        Y

        ^
  NO    |    NE
        |
-----------------> X
        |
  SO    |    SE
```

Você quer ler umas coordenadas assim, com a  origem em (M,N), em K ciclos de (X,Y) pontos e dizer em que quadrante eles estão. Ou se estão na divisa.

Tomei a liberdade de editar seu programa e incluir umas coisas para contornar o problema do uso de `scanf()`, na linha do que escrevi acima. E incluí um pouco de álgebra de Boole para simplificar a lógica e usar uma tabela, a tal Tabela Verdade dos tempos de [George, o criador](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole).
Mudei a entrada dos pontos para usar uma vírgula entre eles, achei mais condizente com a notação cartesiana, e é melhor para `scanf()`
A lógica, a álgebra de Boole e um *bitmask*

- se `(X>N)` está do lado Norte
- se `(Y<M)` está do lado Oeste
- usando o valor 2 para estar ao NORTE e o valor 1 para estar ao LESTE você tem uma tabela de 4 valores.
- se o endereço `(X,Y)` está sobre um dos eixos, está "na divisa" como escreveu em seu programa, e então está é a quinta opção.
- em C e outras linguagens ZERO é FALSO. 1 é verdade. Então você entende que **toda expressão vira um número**. (X>2) vale 1 se X for maior que 2, ou vale 0

Então pode usar uma tabela assim

```
    const char* quadrante[5] = {
        " na Divisa de ",
        " a SO de ",
        " a NO de ",
        " a SE de ",
        " a NE de " };
```

E uma variável `int idx = 1`; e calcular o índice assim:

```
            if (X > N) idx += 2;
            if (Y > M) idx += 1;
```

E usar um único printf() para escrever a resposta no programa.

```
            printf("    (%d,%d)%s(%d,%d)\n", X, Y,
              quadrante[( 1 + (X>N)+(X>N) + (Y>M)) * (X!=N) * (Y!=M)], M, N);
```

E ver assim na tela

```
    (-1,-1) a SO de (0,0)
```

Talvez ache mais simples. O computador por certo acha: é absurdamente rápido avaliar um *bitmask*. E mais fácil de controlar a lógica: você só precisa ajustar a tal tabela verdade, como dizia George. Não precisa caçar código no programa.

#### Eis um programa de teste

Digitado em cima de seu código com umas mudanças para se proteger de dados inválidos no teclado.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* quadrante[5] = {
        " na Divisa de ",
        " a SO de ",
        " a NO de ",
        " a SE de ",
        " a NE de " };
    unsigned ciclos = 0;
    int N, M; // n e m = origem do grafico, divisas para as regioes
    int X, Y; // onde a residencia se encontra
    int res = 0;
    int idx = 0;
    int ch;
    const char* mascara = " %d,%d";

    // loop ate ler algo
    do { printf("\nTotal de ciclos (0 para encerrar): "); }
    while ((res = scanf("%d", &ciclos)) != 1);

    while (ciclos != 0)
    {
        printf("=> %d ciclos\n", ciclos);
        // loop ate ler dois valores 
        do { 
            printf("\nCoordenadas N,M separadas por virgula: ");
            res = scanf(mascara, &N, &M);
            do { ch = getc(stdin); } while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF));
        }   while (res!=2);

        for (unsigned i = 1; i <= ciclos; i++)
        {   // UM CICLO
            idx = 1; // cada (X,Y) tem um indice
            printf("\n=> Ciclo %d de %d\n", i, ciclos);
            do {
                printf("\n    Onde fica? X,Y separados por virgula: ");
                res = scanf(mascara, &X, &Y);
                do { ch = getc(stdin); } while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF));
            }   while (res!=2);
            // menos contas: (X>N) vale 2 (Y>M) vale 1
            if (X > N) idx += 2;
            if (Y > M) idx += 1;
            printf("    (%d,%d)%s(%d,%d)\n", X, Y,
              quadrante[( 1 + (X>N)+(X>N) + (Y>M)) * (X!=N) * (Y!=M)], M, N);
        };  // for()

        do { printf("\nTotal de ciclos (0 para encerrar): "); }
        while ((res = scanf(" %d", &ciclos)) != 1);
    };
    return 0;
};  // main()
```

#### Eis uma execução normal

```
Total de ciclos (0 para encerrar): 8
=> 8 ciclos

Coordenadas N,M separadas por virgula: 0,0

=> Ciclo 1 de 8

    Onde fica? X,Y separados por virgula: 1,1
    (1,1) a NE de (0,0)

=> Ciclo 2 de 8

    Onde fica? X,Y separados por virgula: 1,-1
    (1,-1) a SE de (0,0)

=> Ciclo 3 de 8

    Onde fica? X,Y separados por virgula: -1,-1
    (-1,-1) a SO de (0,0)

=> Ciclo 4 de 8

    Onde fica? X,Y separados por virgula: -1,1
    (-1,1) a NO de (0,0)

=> Ciclo 5 de 8

    Onde fica? X,Y separados por virgula: 0,1
    (0,1) na Divisa de (0,0)

=> Ciclo 6 de 8

    Onde fica? X,Y separados por virgula: 1,0
    (1,0) na Divisa de (0,0)

=> Ciclo 7 de 8

    Onde fica? X,Y separados por virgula: 0,0
    (0,0) na Divisa de (0,0)

=> Ciclo 8 de 8

    Onde fica? X,Y separados por virgula: 1,1
    (1,1) a NE de (0,0)

Total de ciclos (0 para encerrar): 0
```

O programa fica em loop nas leituras até ler os valores esperados.

[compilado em Windows com o compilador CL 19.27]